# How to print a new line in the kafka console consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to send some data (after KStream to KTable join) to the output topic "**Topic-B**" in the following format :

```
{"Key":"1234"}
{"value":"#1#Hello#ABC#CDF#ZZ["XYZ"]"
  Date:2018-09-24 11:25:02

 &&MELLO" 
}
```

(observer there is a new line after first line(of value) and another new line after the "Date")

So far I'm able to get the result of "KStream to Ktable" to the output topic "**Topic-B**" but in the below format :

```
{"Key":"1234"} {"value":"#1#Hello#ABC#CDF#ZZ["XYZ"]"Date:2018-09-24 11:25:02&&MELLO"}
```

(See everything in a single line)

I've tired using newLine "\n" like below :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("#"+tokens[1] + "**\n**");
sb.append("Date: "+sdf.format(date)+"**\n\n**");                    
sb.append("&&MELLO");
```

But the data in the "Topic-B" is as follows :

```
{"Key":"1234"} {"value":"#1#Hello#ABC#CDF#ZZ["XYZ"]"**\n**Date:2018-09-24 11:25:02**\n\n**&&MELLO"}
```

(Observer that "\n" is also being printed (using Kafka-avro-console-consumer) in the single line)

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue? or suggest any other method of doing it?
By the way, I'm using Confluent-5.0.0 with zookeeper,kakfa and SchemaRegistry started.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok the issue is resolved as when I try to print the output using logger, the desired output is coming. May be it's the way kafka-avro-console-consumer showing?

Comment: If you're producing Avro, you would typically create new fields for your internal value fields, not new-line separate them.